# File object variable is not printing newline for \n in the string

Tags: python

I have a text file that contains `"b'Fenced Ports :\t\t\tNone\nFenced circuits :\t\tN/A\n'"` as text. I am opening this text file in read mode, creating a file object, reading the file content using `read()` function and storing it in a variable `x`. This variable `x` is of type `str`.
But when I am trying to print this `str` variable `x`. It doesn't convert `\t` and `\n` into tab space and newline respectively.

```
fo=open("hcc.txt", "r")
data = fo.read()
print(data)
fo.close()
```

Output:

```
b'Fenced Ports :\t\t\tNone\nFenced circuits :\t\tN/A\n'
```

I need it like below:

```
Fenced Ports :          None
Fenced circuits :       N/A
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that, all of your file's lines start with `"b'` and end with `'"`

```py
with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    print(
        "".join(
            [line.replace("\\t", "\t").replace("\\n", "\n")[3:-3] for line in f]
        ).strip()
    )
```

```sh
Fenced Ports :                  None
Fenced circuits :               N/A
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you have provided should give the correct output. `open` uses text mode by default, so tabs and newlines should not appear as \t and \n when you print it. Based on the output you've given, it looks like you're opening the file in binary mode (hence the `b` at the start of the output), which causes tabs and newlines to be printed verbatim. Ensure that you are running the same code you provided in your question; make sure you do not have "b" in the second argument to `open`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that Python substitutes the newline and tab characters when we put the text into the variable as in:

```
var="Hello\nWorld!"
```

but not when we read a script. It is as though we wrote

```
var="Hello\\nWorld
```

If there is a newline or tab in the file it will be read correctly.
You could run string substitution to replace \n and \t with the "\n" and which "\t" which will therefore be parsed and substituted.